# Can not see underscores (_) in Stata Editor

Tags: stata

I can see underscores (_) everywhere in Stata (Variable list, properties, history, results, command), except in the Do-file Editor. This image show where I can see the _:

[image]

The image below show the editor. Notice how autocompletion reveals that the underscore is part of the variable name, but it does not show in the editor. This is extremely annoying.

[image]

I have Stata 16 in Ubuntu 20.04. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem using Monospace font in Stata (default Stata font in Linux systems). Changing the font solves the problem. ([Source](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1575641-do-file-editor-not-showing-underscore))